# Perl Substitution

Tags: regex, perl, substitution

I have a variable which stores the path on Windows. I want to replace all the \ with / in the path.

for eg. `$path = C:\Users\scripts.ps1`

Am new to Perl and tried something like

```
$path = s/\\////
```

But it didnt work. can you please help me out....

Comment: Actually the right answer depends on why you want to do this. So the right answer may be "don't do it" as well.

Answer (score 10):

If you want a cross-platform way of doing this, use [File::Spec](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::Spec).

```
($volume,$directories,$file) = File::Spec->splitpath( $path );
@dirs = File::Spec->splitdir( $directories );
```

Then use `catpath` to join it back.

Answer (score 6):

Your attempt was almost right. Let's take a closer look:

```
$path = s/\\////
             ^
```

First, to make the substitution operate on the `$path` variable, you need to **use the [`=~` binding operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Binding-Operators)**, not just the plain assignment operator. Next, since you used the customary slash character as your substitution delimiter, the slash indicated above actually marks the *end* of the substitution command, and the remaining two slashes are just garbage. It looks like you might have thought that the rule for by-passing the special properties of a character is to double it. If your only example is the backslash, then that rule might make sense, but the rule is actually to **prefix special characters with backslashes**. Replace that highlighted slash with a backslash, and it becomes the *escape character*, so we by-pass the special function of the next slash to treat it as a plain slash, allowing the slash after that to properly terminate the substitution:

```
$path =~ s/\\/\//
```

But that's hard to read. Luckily, you're not *required* to use slash as the substitution delimiter; you can use just about any character you want. **Choose a delimiter that doesn't resemble the text you're trying to substitute**, and your code can be more readable. Details are in *perlop* under [*Quote and quote-like operators*](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators). When the character you choose forms a pair with another character, you use both to enclose the two parts of the expression. And furthermore, since you probably want to replace *all* the slashes in your string, you should use the `g` modifier at the end, telling it to match *globally* instead of stopping after the first substitution. Bringing it all together:

```
$path =~ s{\\}{/}g
```

Since you're substituting a single character for another single character, you can use the more specialized **[transliteration operator `tr`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators)** instead of `s`. It automatically applies globally.

```
$path =~ tr{\\}{/}
```

Finally, if this is more than just a one-off path operation (i.e., you do this multiple times in the script, or the script will be maintained for a while), or you need your code to run the same on multiple platforms, **consider using the [File::Spec](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::Spec) module**. It lets you split and join path components using the right separator for whatever platform you're running on.

Comment: @Rob : What about global matching for `s///` ?

Comment: Thank you, @Zaid. Feel free to make whatever other improvements you wish; that's why I marked my answer as community wiki. (Also because mine is just a summary of the other four answers.)

Answer (score 4):

For some variety, lets also mention the `tr` operator

```
$path =~ tr!\\!/!;
```

or

```
$path =~ y!\\!/!;
```

will replace all instances of `\` with `/` in `$path`

Answer (score 3):

`$path =~ s/\\/\//g;`

The `g` at the end replaces *each* occurence of `\` rather than only 
the first one.

Comment: Would be much clearer if you used `!`, `#` or `{}` delimiters. It would also avoid the extra backslash. I suppose it's down to personal preference...

Answer (score 3):

If you use a different pattern delimiter, you don't need to escape the forward slash:

```
$path =~ s!\\!/!g;
```